# toc, numberline and hyperref incompatibility?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

Since an update of my Texlive distribution I have some issues with a class file I wrote for my students.

The class file:

```
%Class declaration
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{cmpreport}[20/08/2020 v5.4 (Pierre Chardaire) Third year Project Reports]
%
% Base this class on KOMA script article class file
% A 5mm binding is added to margin
%
\LoadClass[12pt,BCOR=0.5cm,twoside=false]{scrartcl}
%
%\KOMAoptions{appendixprefix=true}.
% Required packages
%
% Font combination
%
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}                 %doc 3 format
\RequirePackage[scaled=0.9]{helvet}       %doc 3 format
\RequirePackage{courier}                  %doc 3 format
%\RequirePackage{ccfonts,eulervm}         %doc 1 format
%\renewcommand{\mathbf}{\mathbold}        %doc 1 format
%\RequirePackage{lmodern}                 %doc 2 format
%\RequirePackage[math]{iwona}             %doc 2 format
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %doc 2 format
%
% needed for changing geometry of marksheets
%
\RequirePackage{geometry}
%
% for citing (and necessary for APA style)
%
\RequirePackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
%
% Students will have figures in their report
%
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
%
% Ensure that table captions are above tables and figure captions are below figure
% independently of the position of the caption command in the latex source
%
\RequirePackage{float}
%\floatstyle{komabelow}
%\restylefloat{figure}
%\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{5pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
%\floatstyle{komaabove}
%\restylefloat{table}
%\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{5pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
%
% KOMA-script package for headings
%
\RequirePackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
%
% Enables to handle url in citations
% Also allow clickable section/citations/refs in PDF
%
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
%
% Links are underlined, but these lines do not appear in printed PDF
%
%%%%%% PC \hypersetup{colorlinks=false,pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1}}
%
% url wrapping
%
%%%%%% PC \g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds}
%
% url style: more compact than default tt 
%
%%%%%% PC \def\url@ukostyle{%
%%%%%% PC \@ifundefined{selectfont}{\def\UrlFont{\normalfont\sffamily}}{\def\UrlFont{\normalfont\sffamily\slshape}}} 
%%%%%% PC \urlstyle{uko}
%
% Captions are left aligned
%
\RequirePackage[justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
%
% Numbering of figures and table
%
%\RequirePackage{chngcntr}
%\counterwithin{figure}{section}
%\counterwithin{table}{section}
%\counterwithin{equation}{section}
%
% Creation of better tables
%
\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{\dimexpr #1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\hspace{0pt}}p{\dimexpr #1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}p{\dimexpr #1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}m{\dimexpr #1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}
%
\newlength{\arrayrulewidthOriginal}
\newcommand{\Hline}[1]{%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidthOriginal}{\arrayrulewidth}}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{#1 pt}}\hline%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{\arrayrulewidthOriginal}}}
%
\newcommand{\LL}{\RaggedRight}
\newcommand{\RR}{\RaggedLeft}
\newcommand{\CC}{\Centering}
%
%
% As we don't want students to change the cmidrule weight we can make the option format 
% more consistent
% 
\RequirePackage{xparse}
%
\let\@originalcmidrule\cmidrule
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\cmidrule}{o m}{%
\IfNoValueTF{#1} 
       {\@originalcmidrule{#2}}
       {\@originalcmidrule (#1){#2}}
}
\renewcommand{\lightrulewidth}{\cmidrulewidth}
\newcommand{\uhrule}{\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]}
%
% To align numbers on decimal points in tables
% amongst other things
%
\RequirePackage{siunitx}
%
% To simplify use of multicolumns
%
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\mcc}{o d() m}{% 
\IfNoValueTF{#1} 
    {%    
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\multicolumn{1}{c}{#3}}
        {\multicolumn{1}{C{#2}}{#3}}
    }
    {%    
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#3}}
        {\multicolumn{#1}{C{#2}}{#3}}        
    }
}
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\mcl}{o d() m}{% 
\IfNoValueTF{#1} 
    {%    
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\multicolumn{1}{l}{#3}}
        {\multicolumn{1}{L{#2}}{#3}}
    }
    {%    
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\multicolumn{#1}{l}{#3}}
        {\multicolumn{#1}{L{#2}}{#3}}        
    }
}
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\mcr}{o d() m}{% 
\IfNoValueTF{#1} 
    {%    
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\multicolumn{1}{r}{#3}}
        {\multicolumn{1}{R{#2}}{#3}}
    }
    {%    
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\multicolumn{#1}{r}{#3}}
        {\multicolumn{#1}{R{#2}}{#3}}        
    }
}
%
%
% table with tablenotes
%
\RequirePackage{threeparttable}
%
% to create note in middle of text
%
\newcommand{\mtnote}[1]{\textsuperscript{\TPTtagStyle{#1}}}
\g@addto@macro\TPT@opt@flushleft{\labelsep.0em}
%
% table environment
%
\let\@originaltable\table
\let\@endoriginaltable\endtable
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{cmptable}{o m}
{\IfNoValueTF{#1} 
       {\@originaltable\threeparttable\caption{#2}}
       {\@originaltable[#1]\threeparttable\caption{#2}}}
{\endthreeparttable\@endoriginaltable}
%
\renewcommand{\TPTminimum}{\textwidth}
\newcommand*{\note}[1]{\item[\hspace{-2em}]#1}
%
\let\@originaltablenotes\tablenotes
\let\@endoriginaltablenotes\endtablenotes
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{cmptablenotes}{}
{\footnotesize\@originaltablenotes[flushleft]}
{\@endoriginaltablenotes}
%
% For creating figures with subfigures
%
\RequirePackage{subcaption}
%
% Figure environment
%
\let\@originalfigure\figure
\let\@endoriginalfigure\endfigure
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{cmpfigure}{o m}
{  \IfNoValueTF{#1} 
       {\@originalfigure}
       {\@originalfigure[#1]}}
{\caption{#2}\@endoriginalfigure}
%
% To create conditional lists of tables and list of figures
%
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndEnvironment{cmpfigure}{\gdef\there@is@a@figure{}} 
\AtEndEnvironment{cmptable}{\gdef\there@is@a@table{}} 
\AtEndEnvironment{figure}{\gdef\there@is@a@figure{}} 
\AtEndEnvironment{table}{\gdef\there@is@a@table{}} 
\AtEndDocument{\ifdefined\there@is@a@figure\label{fig:was:used:in:doc}\fi} 
\AtEndDocument{\ifdefined\there@is@a@table\label{tab:was:used:in:doc}\fi} 
%
\newcommand{\conditionalLoF}{\@ifundefined{r@fig:was:used:in:doc}{}{\listoffigures}}%
\newcommand{\conditionalLoT}{\@ifundefined{r@tab:was:used:in:doc}{}{\listoftables}}%
%
\newif\if@list
\@listtrue
\newcommand{\nolist}{\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{}\renewcommand{\listoftables}{}\@listfalse}
%
% For list of figures and list of tables on single page
%
\newif\if@twoPageLists
\@twoPageListstrue
\newcommand{\onePageLists}{\@twoPageListsfalse}
%
% For table of content
%
\RequirePackage[title,titletoc,toc]{appendix}
\RequirePackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\settocbibname{References}
%
% For mathematics
%
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
%
% for the admnin option (i.e. to write tutorials in same format as report)
%
\let\@originalauthor\author
\global\let\@myauthor\@empty
\renewcommand*{\author}[1]{%
\@originalauthor{#1}\renewcommand*{\@myauthor}{#1}}
\def\myname{\@myauthor}
%
% supervisor's name
%
\newcommand*{\supervisor}[1]{\renewcommand*{\@supervisor}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\@supervisor}{\ClassError{cmpfinalreport}{No \string\supervisor\space given}{}}
\def\mysupervisor{\@supervisor}
%
% registration number 
%
\newcommand*{\registration}[1]{\renewcommand*{\@registration}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\@registration}{\ClassError{cmpfinalreport}{No \string\registration\space given}{}}
\def\myreg{\@registration}
%
% course code
%
\newcommand*{\ccode}[1]{\renewcommand*{\@ccode}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\@ccode}{\ClassError{cmpfinalreport}{No \string\ccode\space given}{}}
%
% acknowledgements
% (used in final report only if students wants to include acknowledgements)
%
\global\let\@acknowledgements\@empty
\newcommand{\acknowledgements}[1]{\renewcommand{\@acknowledgements}{#1}}
%
% summary (replace use of abstract environment)
%
\newcommand{\summary}[1]{\renewcommand{\@summary}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@summary}{\ClassError{cmpfinalreport}{No \string\summary\space given}{}}
%
% preface for tutorial, e.g. used for handbook
%
\global\let\@preface\@empty
\newcommand{\preface}[1]{\renewcommand{\@preface}{#1}}
%
% watermark for confidential reports
%
\global\let\@confstatement\@empty
\newcommand{\confidential}[1]{
 \def\@confstatement{#1}
 \RequirePackage{eso-pic}
 \AddToShipoutPictureFG{
   \put(0,0){%
     \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
       \vfill
       % free clipart image from https://www.clker.com/clipart-624476.html
       \includegraphics[width=0.3\paperwidth,height=0.3\paperheight,%
                        keepaspectratio]{confidentialWatermark.png}%
       \vfill
     }}}}
%
% to create a Gantt chart
%
\RequirePackage{pgfgantt}
%
% to pass to marksheet
%
\def\mytitle{\@title}
\def\meccode{\@ccode}
%
% Options. cmpreport can be used with four exclusive (exclusivity not tested) options
% proposal/review/progress/final for the four pieces of work returned by students
%
\newif\if@nottutorial
\@nottutorialtrue
\DeclareOption{tutorial}{
    \@nottutorialfalse
    \newcommand{\headingcmp}[1]{\renewcommand{\@headingcmp}{#1}}
    \newcommand{\@headingcmp}{Third year project tutorial}
}
\newif\if@cmptitlepage
\@cmptitlepagefalse
\DeclareOption{cmptitlepage}{
    \@cmptitlepagetrue
}
\newif\if@intermediate
\@intermediatetrue
\DeclareOption{final}{
    \@intermediatefalse
}
\newif\if@notprogress
\@notprogresstrue
\DeclareOption{progress}{
    \@notprogressfalse
    \newcommand*{\@worktitle}{Progress report}
    \AtBeginDocument{
        \let\default@color\current@color
        %\thispagestyle{empty}
        %\newgeometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
        %\noindent\textbf{\@ccode}
        %\hspace{\stretch{1}}
        %\textbf{Student registration number: \@registration}
        %\\
        %\\
        %\InputIfFileExists{marksheetprogress.tex}{}{\ClassError{cmpfinalreport}{marksheetprogress.tex missing}{}}
        %\restoregeometry
        %\clearpage    
        \setcounter{page}{1}
        \maketitle
        \let\maketitle\relax
    } %\AtBeginDocument
}
%
\DeclareOption{proposal}{
    \newcommand*{\@worktitle}{Project proposal}
    \AtEndDocument{
        \clearpage
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \newgeometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
        \renewcommand\thepage{}
        \noindent{\textbf{\@ccode}}\hspace{\stretch{1}}
        \textbf{Student registration number:\@registration}
        \\
        \\        
        \InputIfFileExists{marksheetproposal.tex}{}{Missing marksheet}
        \restoregeometry
    } %\AtEndDocument
} %\DeclareOption{proposal}
\DeclareOption{review}
{
    \newcommand*{\@worktitle}{Literature review}
    \AtEndDocument{
        \clearpage
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \newgeometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
        \renewcommand\thepage{}
        \textbf{\noindent\@ccode}
        \hspace{\stretch{1}}
        \textbf{Student registration number: \@registration}
        \\
        \\
        \InputIfFileExists{marksheetlitrev.tex}{}{Missing marksheet}
        \restoregeometry       
    } %\AtEndDocument
} %\DeclareOption{review}
\ProcessOptions
%
\if@notprogress
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \let\default@color\current@color
    \maketitle
    \let\maketitle\relax
}
\else
%\IfFileExists{marksheetprogress.tex}{\RequirePackage[-22,nonofiles]{pagesel}}
%{
%{\Large Where is your marksheet \emph{marksheetprogress.tex}?}
%\RequirePackage[-1,nonofiles]{pagesel}}
\RequirePackage[-21,nonofiles]{pagesel}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2} 
\fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% headings
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\if@nottutorial
  %
  \newpagestyle{reportheadings}
  {(0pt,0pt){}{}{\@ccode\hfill\headmark}(\textwidth,1pt)} % header
  {(\textwidth,1pt){}{}{Reg:~\@registration\hfill\pagemark}(0pt,0pt)} % footer
  \newpagestyle{titlepageheading}
  {(0pt,0pt){}{}{\@ccode\hfill\@worktitle}(\textwidth,1pt)} % header
  {(\textwidth,1pt){}{}{Reg:~\@registration\hfill{}For\space\@supervisor}(0pt,0pt)} % footer
\else
  \newpagestyle{reportheadings}
  {(0pt,0pt){}{}{\@headingcmp\hfill\headmark}(\textwidth,1pt)} % header
  {(\textwidth,1pt){}{}{\@myauthor\hfill\pagemark}(0pt,0pt)} % footer
\fi
%
% Because \maketitle issue a \thisplagestyle{plain} at
% the end of execution
%
\g@addto@macro{\maketitle}{\thispagestyle{reportheadings}}
\if@nottutorial
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  % Inital proposal/literrature survey
  % (the name of supervisor appears in te title page headings)
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \if@intermediate
    \renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
        \thispagestyle{titlepageheading}
        \begin{center}
                \vspace*{\fill}
                \let\footnote\thanks
                {\LARGE\bfseries \@title\par}%
                \vskip 1em\relax
                \ifx\@myauthor\@empty
                    \relax
                \else
                    {\Large  \@myauthor}\\[\baselineskip]
                \fi
                {\large registration:~\@registration}\par
                \vskip 2\baselineskip\relax
                \ifx\@confstatement\@empty
                    \relax
                \else
                    \@confstatement\par
                \fi
                \vspace*{\fill}
        \end{center}
        \newpage
    }
    \pagestyle{reportheadings}
    \else
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Final report
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
    \RequirePackage[-55,nonofiles]{pagesel}
    \newcounter{oldpage}
    \renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
        
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        %\newgeometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
        %\InputIfFileExists{marksheetsfinal.tex}{}{Missing marksheet}
        %\restoregeometry
        %\clearpage    
        \setcounter{page}{1}        
        \pagenumbering{roman}
        \thispagestyle{empty}     
        \newgeometry{left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm}
        { \centering
          \vspace*{\baselineskip}
          \ifx\@myauthor\@empty
              \relax
          \else
              {\Large  \@myauthor}\\[\baselineskip]
          \fi
          { Registration number~\@registration}\\[\baselineskip]
          {\Large \the\year}\\[\baselineskip]
          \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{4pt}
          \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\
          \begingroup
             \hyphenpenalty 10000
             \exhyphenpenalty 10000
             {\noindent\Huge\bfseries \@title\par}
          \endgroup
          \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{5pt}
          \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\\
          \vskip 2\baselineskip\relax
          { Supervised by~\@supervisor}\par
          \vskip 2\baselineskip\relax
          \ifx\@confstatement\@empty
              \relax
          \else
              \@confstatement\par
          \fi
          \vspace*{\fill}
          \includegraphics[width=3cm]{uealogo.png}\\
          { University of East Anglia}\\
          { Faculty of Science}\\
          { School of Computing Sciences}\\
          \par
        }
        \restoregeometry
        \newpage
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        %
        %  Dealing with optional acknowledgements
        %
        
        \section*{Abstract}
        \@summary
        \ifx\@acknowledgements\@empty
                \relax
        \else
                \section*{Acknowledgements}
                \@acknowledgements
        \fi %
        \newpage
        \tableofcontents
        \newpage
        \if@list
           \conditionalLoF
           \if@twoPageLists 
              \newpage
           \fi
           \conditionalLoT
           \newpage
        \fi
        \setcounter{oldpage}{\value{page}}
        \pagenumbering{arabic}
        \setcounter{page}{\value{oldpage}}
      }
      \pagestyle{reportheadings}
      %\pagestyle{plain}
      \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\fi
%
%
%
\else
\if@cmptitlepage
    \newcounter{oldpage}
    \headingcmp{Third year project handbook}    
    \renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
        \pagenumbering{roman}
        \thispagestyle{empty}     
        \newgeometry{left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm}
        { \centering
            \vspace*{\baselineskip}
            \ifx\@myauthor\@empty
            \relax
            \else
            {\Large  \@myauthor}\\[\baselineskip]
            \fi
            {\Large Version \@ccode}\\[\baselineskip]
            \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{4pt}
            \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\
            \begingroup
            \hyphenpenalty 10000
            \exhyphenpenalty 10000
            {\noindent\Huge\bfseries \@title\par}
            \endgroup
            \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{5pt}
            \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\\
            \vskip 2\baselineskip\relax
            \vspace*{\fill}
            \includegraphics[width=3cm]{uealogo.png}\\
            { University of East Anglia}\\
            { Faculty of Science}\\
            { School of Computing Sciences}\\
            \par
        }
        \restoregeometry
        \newpage
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \ifx\@preface\@empty
           \relax
        \else
           \section*{Preface}
           \@preface
           \newpage
        \fi
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \tableofcontents
        \newpage
        \if@list
           \conditionalLoF
           \if@twoPageLists 
              \newpage
           \fi
           \conditionalLoT
           \newpage
        \fi
        \setcounter{oldpage}{\value{page}}
        \pagenumbering{arabic}
        \setcounter{page}{\value{oldpage}}
    }

\fi
\pagestyle{reportheadings}
\fi %end \if@nottutorial
```

A minimal example:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Change the option between square brackets
% depending on the document you have to write:
%
% proposal    for the initial proposal
% review      for the literature review
% progress    for the progress report
% final       for the final report
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[final]{cmpreport}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%  Fill in the fields with:
%
%  your project title
%  your name
%  your registration number
%  your supervisor's name
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{Use of the template}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% The author's name is ignored if the following command 
% is not present in the document
%
% Before submitting a PDF of your final report to the 
% project database you may comment out the command
% if you are worried about lack of anonimity.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\author{H. P\'etard}

\registration{31415927}
\supervisor{Dr Ersatz Stanislaus Pondiczery}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Fill in the field with your module code.
% this should be:
%
% for BIS project moule    -> CMP-6012Y
% for STATS project module -> CMP-6028Y
% for CS project module    -> CMP-6013Y
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ccode{CMP-6012Y}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Comment out if confidential report.
% The command should be used if the project is subjected 
% to a Non Disclosure Agreement.
%
% Three examples of the use of the \confidential command. 
% Please ask your supervisor what confidential statement 
% should be used, if appropriate.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\confidential{}

%\confidential{The contents of this report remain confidential for two years and should not be discussed or disclosed to any third party without the prior written permission from the School of Computing Sciences, the University of East Anglia}

%\confidential{The information contained in this document is confidential, privileged and only for the information of the intended recipient and may not be used, published or redistributed without the prior written consent of FruitName Ltd}

\summary{
This document explains how to use the class file \texttt{cmpreport.cls} to write your reports.
The class file has been designed to simplify your life; many things are done for you. As a consequence
some commands presented here are specific to the class file whether they are new commands or customized versions
of commonly known \LaTeX\ commands.
}

\acknowledgements{
This section is used to acknowledge whoever's support and contribution.
The command that introduces it is ignored in the project proposal, literature review and progress report. It is used in the
final report,  but  is not compulsory. If you do not
have an acknowledgements command in your preamble then there
won't be any acknowledgement section in the document produced. \emph{Abstract} and \emph{Acknowledgements} sections should fit on the same page. 
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% If you do not want a list of figures and a list of tables
% to appear after the table of content then uncomment this line 
%
% Note that the class file contains code to avoid
% producing an empty list section (e.g list of figures) if the 
% list is empty (i.e. no figure in document).
%
% The command also prevents inserting a list of figures or tables 
% anywhere else in the document
%
% Some supervisors think that a report should not contain these
% lists. Please ask your supervisor's opinion.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\nolist

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Comment out if you want your list of figures and list of
% tables on two or more pages, in particular if the lists do not fit 
% on a single page.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\onePageLists


\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}

Before reading this document you should go through the \LaTeX\ tutorials that have been provided for you to learn the
basics of \LaTeX\ such as sectioning, style, lists, referencing, bibliography and mathematics if applicable.
Even if you already  know \LaTeX{}, please at least go through \emph{Tutorial 6: Bibliography and citations
in \LaTeXe{}} and \emph{Tutorial 5: Producing
professional-looking tables}.

The basic structure of your reports is introduced in section~\ref{sec1} with the \LaTeX{} commands used to implement it\footnote{The beginning of your reports, usually the \emph{Introduction} section, should tell the reader about the organisation of the report.}. Section~\ref{sec2} shows how to create figures and gives examples of tables produced with the \verb/cmpreport/ class. Section~\ref{secGantt} shows how you can produce a Gantt chart with \LaTeXe{}. 

\section{The structure of the document} \label{sec1}

As any other \LaTeX{} documents, your report starts by declaring the style of your document. For your final report this is done by issuing the command 
\texttt{\textbackslash{}documentclass\allowbreak [final]\{cmpreport\}}
which means that your report follows the style specified for the \texttt{final} report in the file \texttt{cmpreport.cls}. Your bibliography file (\verb/bib/ file) and any pictures you use in your figures
should be placed in the same directory as your report. The option \texttt{final}, between the square brackets, must be replaced with \texttt{proposal}, \texttt{review} or \texttt{progress} for the corresponding pieces of assessment.
There is another option \texttt{tutorial} that you will have used if you went through some of my tutorials. However,
this is of no concern when using the class for your reports.

The main differences between the options of interest are:
\begin{itemize}
\item The options \texttt{proposal} and \texttt{review} produce a simple title page and add a ``performance sheet''\footnote{This is not a mark sheet, as this corresponds to a formative piece of coursework. However, your supervisor may indicate a level of performance for each of the criteria in the performance sheet.} at the end of the document that indicates the evaluation criteria
for the corresponding piece of work and provides a comment box for your supervisor. 
\item The option \texttt{progress} produces a mark sheet at the beginning of the document.
\item The option \texttt{final} provides a ``more official'' title page\footnote{You may want to show your report to a future employer.}. It creates a table of contents, and possibly a list of tables and a list of figures (see below). 

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

If I process I get the error message:

Undefined control sequence. ...{\numberline {1}Introduction}{4}{section.1}

If I comment out the line

\RequirePackage{hyperref}

I don't get an error, but obviously I cannot use links in table of contents and the \url command. How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding typesetting material to \Atbegindocument. That is wrong, this hook is not meant for it. In a current LaTeX you can use the begindocument/end hook instead, e.g.

```
\if@notprogress
\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{%
    \let\default@color\current@color
    \maketitle
    \let\maketitle\relax
}
\else
```

With older LaTeX you can use the etoolbox hook `\AfterEndPreamble`.